# Import Fixedwidth file using SSIS

Tags: file, import, ssis, fixed-width

I have a fixed width file with no headers and massive columns about 900 columns.
Is there an easy way to create source metadata as in SSIS either I need to create columns one by one or using scale which is very manual and time taking approach.

Sample Data:

AXC98976GHHL66678787656UKAPPLE+44POS

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you have a breakdown of the metadata? like starting position, length, datatype, name?

Comment: YES I have the metadata and I already created my target table using that, I need help on creating source component as file contains 900 columns with no headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an experiment as I have not ever tried this before, but if you could have your metadata stored in a table. You could load the metadata into a datatable and process each row with that. I have mocked up some sample code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Simulate var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("[path]");
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.Add("AXC98976GHHL66678787656UKAPPLE+44POS");

        var metadata = getMetaData();

        string sql = string.Format(
                @"insert into [your table]
                    values(?,{0})"
                        , new System.Text.StringBuilder().Insert(0, ",?", metadata.Rows.Count - 1).ToString());

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(cstr))
            {
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    foreach (DataRow row in metadata.Rows)
                    {
                        switch (row["DataType"].ToString())
                        {
                            case "string":
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(string.Format("param{0}", row["StartingPosition"]), OleDbType.VarChar, (int)row["Length"]).Value = line.Substring((int)row["StartPosition"], (int)row["Length"]);
                                break;
                            case "int":
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(string.Format("param{0}", row["StartingPosition"]), OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(line.Substring((int)row["StartPosition"], (int)row["Length"]));
                                break;
                            //Add more for each data type
                        }

                    }
                    
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static DataTable getMetaData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(cstr))
        {
            string sql = "select FieldName, DataType, StartPosition, Length from metatdataTable";
            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, will try this and appreciate if I can get the same with low code approach as predominantly I am looking to speedup field creation in the source component as that currently not supports importing column metadata in SSIS.

Comment: That's why i gave you a script task to use against your metadata table.

Answer (score 0):

Two options for generating the connection manager might be:

**Modify the XML in the SSIS Package**

1. Create a flatfile connection manager in the project
2. generate the xml for each column using TextTemplates or even excel
3. paste that into the ssis xml (F7 - xml view of the project)

The xml looks like this:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
          DTS:Format="FixedWidth"
          DTS:LocaleID="1033"
          DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_"
          DTS:RowDelimiter=""
          DTS:TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_"
          DTS:CodePage="1252"
          DTS:ConnectionString="C:\MyFilePath\FixedWidth.txt">
          <DTS:FlatFileColumns>
            <DTS:FlatFileColumn
              DTS:ColumnDelimiter=""
              DTS:ColumnWidth="10"
              DTS:MaximumWidth="10"
              DTS:DataType="129"
              DTS:ObjectName="Column Name"
              DTS:DTSID="{2448DB1E-03F9-4AFC-9B8F-75C71AF3F99B}" --> some guid
              DTS:CreationName="" />
            <DTS:FlatFileColumn
              DTS:ColumnDelimiter=""
              DTS:ColumnWidth="5"
              DTS:MaximumWidth="5"
              DTS:DataType="129"
              DTS:ObjectName="Column Name 2"
              DTS:DTSID="{40B08811-64B1-4B7F-8FA8-48ACA21DCD8E}"
              DTS:CreationName="" />
           </DTS:FlatFileColumns>
        </DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

**Use BIML Express**

1- Add A flat file manager

2- write a loop to add the columns

There's a lot of options for how to write that loop, use a file as a source, do it inline using a .net list, etc.  This is roughly what the biml would look like to generate the ssis package -- once you have the connection manager, you can go about modifying the package manually or use BIML to do the whole thing:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection Name="Flat File Connection Manager" FilePath="C:\MyFilePath\FixedWidth.txt" FileFormat="Flat File Connection Manager" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="Package" Language="None" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="RowType" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude">Before</Variable>
            </Variables>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="Flat File Connection Manager" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" FlatFileType="FixedWidth" RowDelimiter="">
            <Columns>
                <#some foreach loop starts here#>
            <Column Name="Column 0" Length="10" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="" TextQualified="false" ColumnType="FixedWidth" MaximumWidth="10" />
            <Column Name="Column 1" Length="5" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="" TextQualified="false" ColumnType="FixedWidth" MaximumWidth="5" />
            <Column Name="Column 2" Length="6" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="" TextQualified="false" ColumnType="FixedWidth" MaximumWidth="6" />
            <#}#>
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
</Biml>
```

Comment: The first approach looks good fit for my purpose as I can use the SQL code to generate the required xml script for all the columns as the target table is already created using the metadata supplied with the file.